# Sharing an aiohttp.ClientSession between multiple asynchronous callers

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**The goal**

I want to make regular HTTP requests to a REST API. The requests happen at an interval ranging from a few seconds up to multiple hours, depending on the user input. I want to keep a single connection alive and close it in a smart way.

**The questions**

Is there an existing library that provides features similar to what i wrote with the class SessionOneToN?
Would it be possible to use a single session of type aiohttp.ClientSession that runs forever and is never closed?

**What i have tried**

What i have tried does work, but i wonder if there is an established library that can achieve the goals.

**My code**

My application uses the event loop module asyncio, and the HTTP module aiohttp.
My application opens a single session of type aiohttp.ClientSession and shares it between multiple asynchronous callers.
The callers can make their requests concurrently and asynchronously.
Whenever all callers have received their responses at the same time, the aiohttp.ClientSession is closed. A new aiohttp.ClientSession is opened as necessary when a caller makes a new request.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import sys

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305548/sharing-an-aiohttp-clientsession-between-multiple-asynchronous-callers'

# The callers look like so
async def request():
    async with session() as s:
        async with s.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


# The session manager looks like so:

class SessionOneToN:
    """ Manage one session that is reused by multiple clients, instantiate a new
    session object from the given session_class as required. Provide a context
    manager for accessing the session. The session_class returns a context
    manager when instantiated, this context manager is referred to as the
    internal context manager, and is entered when the first
    client enters the context manager returned by context_manager, and is exited
    when the last client exits context_manager."""
    def __init__(self, session_class):
        self.n = 0
        self.session_class = session_class
        self.context = None
        self.aenter_result = None

    async def plus(self):
        self.n += 1
        if self.n == 1:
            # self.context: The internal context manager
            self.context = context = self.session_class()
            # self.aenter_result: The result from entering the internal context
            # manager
            self.aenter_result = await context.__aenter__()
        assert self.aenter_result is not None
        return self.aenter_result

    def minus(self):
        self.n -= 1
        if self.n == 0:
            return True

    def cleanup(self):
        self.context = None
        self.aenter_result = None


    @asynccontextmanager
    async def get_context(self):
        try:
            aenter_result = await self.plus()
            yield aenter_result
        except:
            if self.minus():
                if not await self.context.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info()):
                    self.cleanup()
                    raise
                self.cleanup()
        else:
            if self.minus():
                await self.context.__aexit__(None, None, None)
                self.cleanup()


class SessionOneToNaiohttp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sotn = SessionOneToN(aiohttp.ClientSession)

    def get_context(self):
        return self.sotn.get_context()


sotnaiohttp = SessionOneToNaiohttp()

def session():
    return sotnaiohttp.get_context()

response_text = asyncio.run(request())
print(response_text[0:10])
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to hold a single connection to a remote HTTP server open *for a few hours* or even *indefinitely* ? Because even if you get that configured on your end, the remote server is probably not going to play along.

Comment: Also, please post *all* of the code for the session manager, including the import statements. As a rule, someone else should be able to copy and paste your code and be able to run it with little or no additional work (and certainly no need to guess about sections that were left out in the post).

Comment: @Z4-tier > Are you saying you want to hold a single connection to a remote HTTP server open for a few hours or even indefinitely ?
No

Comment: The idiomatic approach is for `request` functions to accept a session and use it. The session is provided by their caller, which is responsible for constructing and tearing down the session.